# How do I structure my RequireJS project so that it can be optimized?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js

As the title says, I'm currently trying to set up my project so that the optimizer can run on it.

I'm looking to support a [multi-page shim style configuration](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim).  That is: A common script, with sibling scripts that will be loaded dynamically at runtime.

My project is also making use of dependencies installed via bower which are set to go into the `vendor` directory.  There is also a `node_modules` directory, although it does not contain anything for the client and should be completely ignored.

Here's the structure I have so far:

```
/
    node_modules/
    vendor/
    some-code/
        a-script.js
    more-code/
        another-script.js
    common.js
    main.js
    runtime.js
    build.js
```

Really all I'd like as a result of this process are two files in my build destination corresponding to `main.js` and `runtime.js`.  Where the compiled `main` would be initially loaded and the compiled `runtime` might be loaded at runtime but only contains dependencies that are new to the graph.

Questions & Issues:

- If my `common.js` shims scripts from `vendor` is there anything about my directory structure that might present a problem during an r.js build?
- I noticed that when running r.js, it tries to minify everything in `node_modules`, which is wrong as I don't want it touching anything in `node_modules`.
- r.js also seems to be minifying everything in `vendor` which seems wrong.  Shouldn't it assemble all the files and then minify them after without touching the originals found in the `vendor` directory?
- After being built, my `dist` directory ends up containing a full copy of my full project and directory structure with all .js files minified.  I was under the impression that all it would contain is at most, two .js files with everything inlined?  Is this possible?

Here's my `build.js`/`build.json` file:

```
{

    "mainConfigFile": "common.js",
    "dir": "dist",
    "modules": [

        {
            "name": "main"
        },
        {
            "name": "runtime",
            "exclude": [
                "common"
            ]
        }

    ]

}
```

Comment: I can't speak for all of that now, but -- if `r.js` is set up properly, it will write everything out to a NEW directory.  So yes, it will turn all the files into your `modules` directory into a big, merged file.  It should just do it in a build directory, not your main one.

Answer (score 0):

- Your directory structure looks fine, though it is common practice to put everything you're working on into a source directory and then build (using gulp or grunt) into a build directory.
- That is the correct behavior r.js. It will copy everything you've required (including node modules) into a single build file. This is better for performance because you'll only be making a single HTTP request instead of a bajillion for all of your node modules. It doesn't modify anything in node_modules
- Nope, that's correct, same as above.
- I don't think it's possible to selectively build some files and asynchronously load the rest. I don't know why'd you want to do that though, as it could cause a pretty big performance hit.

By the way, the community seems to be moving away from require.js and towards browserify. You might want to [check it out](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: It's not that it's copying it into a single build file.  It's copying the entire directory structure.  Along with the single build file.  So `dist/some-code/a-script.js` is being created.  Is that right?

Comment: You can selectively build some files and async the rest. You just have to setup a 'dummy' module that includes the ones you wish to pre-load, then include that script in your document.  It will async anything NOT there.

Comment: It seems to have already done both things at once though.  It's both built a `dist/common.js` as well as `dist/some-code/a-script.js` even though let's say, `common.js` is already defining `some-code/a-script.js` as a dependency...